# How to update models and DBContext class in Entity Framework core (if database created first)

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity, dbcontext

As the title indicates I Have an SQL server database already made and I excuted the following command to generate DBContext class and the model:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "connectionstring" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

later on a table has been added through SQL server( Not through a model migration command)

is there a way to generate the related model for it and update the dbContext ?

if i re-excute the command above I would get Build Failed

Comment: Hi @Angular Dev, I think you need first check the `Error List` if any error in your project. Build Failed is because your project contains any error.

Answer (score 1):

Use

-Force

Or have a look at EF Core Power Tools.

Answer (score 0):

you want to update model and context if it already exits then you can use update wizard to update model by clicking on edmx diagram , then right click on empty white space and click update model from db